# SQLite.Swift Nested Queries

Tags: swift, sqlite, subquery

I have a tree like scheme where the items can have parent from the same table what I need is to query the items whose parent is deleted

```
select * from items as c where not exists (select p.id from items as p where c.parent_id == p.id)
```

I tried to achieve this as :

```
let child = ItemTable.table.alias("child")
let parent = ItemTable.table.alias("parent")
let parentExists = parent.filter(child[ItemTable.parentId] == parent[ItemTable.id]).exists
let r = child.filter(parentExists)
```

but the last line gives the following compilation error :

```
Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(Select<Bool>)'
```

I can write the whole code in sql and run the query, but I need to achieve this using the ORM provided by SQLite Swift.

Comment: Simpler SQL: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE parent_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM items)`.

Comment: @CL. I need to do it using SQLite.Swift way

Comment: Different SQL would result in a different Swift construct. Anyway, it appears that SQLite.swift does not support subqueries at all; try an outer self join and filter for NULL parents.

Comment: @CL. what I am asking is how to do it using sqlite.swift .. if it supports nested (inner) queries